# Divide by zero error encountered when using count then divide

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to do a count on a field and then 1 divide by this number so i get a decimal.
When using the code below I get error 'Divide by zero error encountered.'

```
COUNT(1/isnull(nullif(current_balance,0),0)) as BALANCE_CURRENT_NU
```

Comment: yes, and what would you expect? also what is the point of combining  `isnull` and `nullif`?

Comment: the result of the count which is firstly divided by 1?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression instructs SQL Server to divide by 0 in some cases.

```
COUNT(1/isnull(nullif(current_balance,0),0))
```

That reduces to

```
COUNT (1/0)
```

for some cases, which is clearly division by 0.

**UPDATE**

If you are trying to get the count of accounts that have a non-null current_balance, try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as BALANCE_CURRENT_NU FROM MyTable 
WHERE current_balance IS NOT NULL
```

If that is not what you intend, please clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Dividing by 0 is certainly not what you intend.  Are you trying to get the count of accounts that have a non-null balance?

Comment: i simply want to divide 1 by the count

Comment: What do you want the result to be if the count is 0?  1/0 is throwing the error.